# Django: SQL queries are slow due to complex sub-queries, how to split or speed them up?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

I need to execute a query set with complex sub-queries like the one below.
It takes a considerable amount of time to execute the query. (8000ms)

I think the slowdown is caused by complex subqueries, but is it possible to split or speed up a single SQL query without generating N+1?

The db lookup we are using and the slow query set this time

```py
# lookups.py
class Groonga(Lookup):
    lookup_name = "groonga"

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        params = lhs_params + rhs_params
        return "%s &@~ %s" % (lhs, rhs), params
```

```py
# queryset
Video.objects.annotate(
    is_viewed=Exists(History.objects.filter(user=user, video=OuterRef("pk"))),
    is_favorited=Exists(
        Favorite.objects.filter(user=user, video=OuterRef("pk"))
    ),
    is_wl=Exists(
        Track.objects.filter(
            playlist__user=user, playlist__is_wl=True, video=OuterRef("pk")
        )
    ),
).filter(
    Q(title__groonga=value)
    | Q(tags__pk__in=Tag.objects.filter(name__groonga=value).values_list("pk")),
    is_public=True,
    published_at__lte=timezone.now(),
).order_by("-published_at").distinct()[:20]
```

SQL query and EXPLAIN ANALYZE results

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT "videos_video"."id",
                "videos_video"."published_at",
                EXISTS
  (SELECT (1) AS "a"
   FROM "videos_history" U0
   WHERE (U0."user_id" IS NULL
          AND U0."video_id" = "videos_video"."id")
   LIMIT 1) AS "is_viewed",
                EXISTS
  (SELECT (1) AS "a"
   FROM "videos_favorite" U0
   WHERE (U0."user_id" IS NULL
          AND U0."video_id" = "videos_video"."id")
   LIMIT 1) AS "is_favorited",
                EXISTS
  (SELECT (1) AS "a"
   FROM "videos_track" U0
   INNER JOIN "videos_playlist" U1 ON (U0."playlist_id" = U1."id")
   WHERE (U1."is_wl"
          AND U1."user_id" IS NULL
          AND U0."video_id" = "videos_video"."id")
   LIMIT 1) AS "is_wl"
FROM "videos_video"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "videos_video_tags" ON ("videos_video"."id" = "videos_video_tags"."video_id")
WHERE ("videos_video"."is_public"
       AND "videos_video"."published_at" <= '2021-12-27 13:34:29.103369+00:00'
       AND ("videos_video"."title" &@~ 'word'
            OR "videos_video_tags"."tag_id" IN
              (SELECT U0."id"
               FROM "videos_tag" U0
               WHERE U0."name" &@~ 'word')))
ORDER BY "videos_video"."published_at" DESC
LIMIT 20;

--                                                                                QUERY PLAN                               
-- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  Limit  (cost=25920044.10..25920044.40 rows=20 width=27) (actual time=8031.477..8083.885 rows=20 loops=1)
--    ->  Unique  (cost=25920044.10..25930094.65 rows=670037 width=27) (actual time=7498.770..7551.175 rows=20 loops=1)
--          ->  Sort  (cost=25920044.10..25921719.19 rows=670037 width=27) (actual time=7498.768..7498.796 rows=30 loops=1)
--                Sort Key: videos_video.published_at DESC, videos_video.id, ((hashed SubPlan 2)), ((hashed SubPlan 4)), ((hashed SubPlan 6))
--                Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 12232kB
--                ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=22049.49..25839171.52 rows=670037 width=27) (actual time=258.201..7221.055 rows=336302 loops=1)
--                      Hash Cond: (videos_video_tags.video_id = videos_video.id)
--                      Filter: ((videos_video.title &@~ 'word'::character varying) OR (hashed SubPlan 7))
--                      Rows Removed by Filter: 1002707
--                      ->  Seq Scan on videos_video_tags  (cost=0.00..24544.40 rows=1338740 width=32) (actual time=0.071..321.529 rows=1338740 loops=1)
--                      ->  Hash  (cost=13230.75..13230.75 rows=290059 width=117) (actual time=229.084..229.085 rows=290059 loops=1)
--                            Buckets: 32768  Batches: 16  Memory Usage: 2899kB
--                            ->  Seq Scan on videos_video  (cost=0.00..13230.75 rows=290059 width=117) (actual time=0.049..80.893 rows=290059 loops=1)
--                                  Filter: (is_public AND (published_at <= '2021-12-27 13:34:29.103369+00'::timestamp with time zone))
--                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 1
--                      SubPlan 2
--                        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on videos_history u0  (cost=4.18..12.63 rows=4 width=16) (actual time=0.005..0.007 rows=0 loops=1)
--                              Recheck Cond: (user_id IS NULL)
--                              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on videos_history_user_id_9a1343c1  (cost=0.00..4.18 rows=4 width=0) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)
--                                    Index Cond: (user_id IS NULL)
--                      SubPlan 4
--                        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on videos_favorite u0_1  (cost=4.19..12.65 rows=5 width=16) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
--                              Recheck Cond: (user_id IS NULL)
--                              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on videos_favorite_user_id_c4289dec  (cost=0.00..4.19 rows=5 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
--                                    Index Cond: (user_id IS NULL)
--                      SubPlan 6
--                        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.36..23.98 rows=2 width=16) (actual time=0.059..0.061 rows=0 loops=1)
--                              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on videos_playlist u1  (cost=4.17..11.27 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.058..0.059 rows=0 loops=1)
--                                    Recheck Cond: (user_id IS NULL)
--                                    Filter: is_wl
--                                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on videos_playlist_user_id_e71a2f32  (cost=0.00..4.17 rows=3 width=0) (actual time=0.054..0.054 rows=0 loops=1)
--                                          Index Cond: (user_id IS NULL)
--                              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on videos_track u0_2  (cost=4.19..12.66 rows=5 width=32) (never executed)
--                                    Recheck Cond: (playlist_id = u1.id)
--                                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on videos_track_playlist_id_bfcae4d7  (cost=0.00..4.19 rows=5 width=0) (never executed)
--                                          Index Cond: (playlist_id = u1.id)
--                      SubPlan 7
--                        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on videos_tag u0_3  (cost=0.00..93.99 rows=6 width=16) (actual time=26.298..26.322 rows=18 loops=1)
--                              Recheck Cond: (name &@~ 'word'::character varying)
--                              Heap Blocks: exact=11
--                              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on pgroonga_tag_index  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=56 width=0) (actual time=0.611..0.612 rows=18 loops=1)
--                                    Index Cond: (name &@~ 'word'::character varying)
--  Planning Time: 3.298 ms
--  JIT:
--    Functions: 75
--    Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
--    Timing: Generation 14.381 ms, Inlining 20.362 ms, Optimization 374.869 ms, Emission 215.556 ms, Total 625.169 ms
--  Execution Time: 8103.397 ms
-- (48 rows)

-- Time: 8108.641 ms (00:08.109)
```

```
 public | pgroonga_tag_index                                           | index | postgres | videos_tag
 public | pgroonga_video_index                                         | index | postgres | videos_video
 public | unique_video                                                 | index | postgres | videos_video
 public | videos_tag                                                   | table | postgres |
 public | videos_tag_is_actress_a294f3fe                               | index | postgres | videos_tag
 public | videos_tag_name_620230b0_like                                | index | postgres | videos_tag
 public | videos_tag_name_key                                          | index | postgres | videos_tag
 public | videos_tag_pkey                                              | index | postgres | videos_tag
 public | videos_video                                                 | table | postgres |
 public | videos_video_is_public_68fc4509                              | index | postgres | videos_video
 public | videos_video_pkey                                            | index | postgres | videos_video
 public | videos_video_published_at_67cd5ed9                           | index | postgres | videos_video
 public | videos_video_tags                                            | table | postgres |
 public | videos_video_tags_pkey                                       | index | postgres | videos_video_tags
 public | videos_video_tags_tag_id_2673cfc8                            | index | postgres | videos_video_tags
 public | videos_video_tags_video_id_8220dbb8                          | index | postgres | videos_video_tags
 public | videos_video_tags_video_id_tag_id_f8d6ba70_uniq              | index | postgres | videos_video_tags
 public | videos_video_views_2035060f                                  | index | postgres | videos_video
```

---------- edit Result after increasing `work_mem` ----------

```sql
                                                                               QUERY PLAN                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=25872934.62..25872934.92 rows=20 width=27) (actual time=5278.335..5312.266 rows=20 loops=1)
   ->  Unique  (cost=25872934.62..25882984.17 rows=669970 width=27) (actual time=4830.339..4864.268 rows=20 loops=1)
         ->  Sort  (cost=25872934.62..25874609.55 rows=669970 width=27) (actual time=4830.336..4830.347 rows=30 loops=1)
               Sort Key: videos_video.published_at DESC, videos_video.id, ((hashed SubPlan 2)), ((hashed SubPlan 4)), ((hashed SubPlan 6))
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 38562kB
               ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=16954.01..25808102.51 rows=669970 width=27) (actual time=182.075..4651.662 rows=336302 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: (videos_video_tags.video_id = videos_video.id)
                     Filter: ((videos_video.title &@~ 'word'::character varying) OR (hashed SubPlan 7))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 1002707
                     ->  Seq Scan on videos_video_tags  (cost=0.00..24549.49 rows=1339049 width=32) (actual time=0.008..120.134 rows=1339049 loops=1)
                     ->  Hash  (cost=13234.99..13234.99 rows=290062 width=117) (actual time=163.414..163.415 rows=290059 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 524288  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 46310kB
                           ->  Seq Scan on videos_video  (cost=0.00..13234.99 rows=290062 width=117) (actual time=0.025..64.256 rows=290059 loops=1)
                                 Filter: (is_public AND (published_at <= '2021-12-27 13:34:29.103369+00'::timestamp with time zone))
                                 Rows Removed by Filter: 100
                     SubPlan 2
                       ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on videos_history u0  (cost=4.18..12.63 rows=4 width=16) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)
                             Recheck Cond: (user_id IS NULL)
                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on videos_history_user_id_9a1343c1  (cost=0.00..4.18 rows=4 width=0) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
                                   Index Cond: (user_id IS NULL)
                     SubPlan 4
                       ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on videos_favorite u0_1  (cost=4.19..12.65 rows=5 width=16) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=0 loops=1)
                             Recheck Cond: (user_id IS NULL)
                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on videos_favorite_user_id_c4289dec  (cost=0.00..4.19 rows=5 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
                                   Index Cond: (user_id IS NULL)
                     SubPlan 6
                       ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.36..23.98 rows=2 width=16) (actual time=0.021..0.022 rows=0 loops=1)
                             ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on videos_playlist u1  (cost=4.17..11.27 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.021..0.022 rows=0 loops=1)
                                   Recheck Cond: (user_id IS NULL)
                                   Filter: is_wl
                                   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on videos_playlist_user_id_e71a2f32  (cost=0.00..4.17 rows=3 width=0) (actual time=0.021..0.021 rows=0 loops=1)
                                         Index Cond: (user_id IS NULL)
                             ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on videos_track u0_2  (cost=4.19..12.66 rows=5 width=32) (never executed)
                                   Recheck Cond: (playlist_id = u1.id)
                                   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on videos_track_playlist_id_bfcae4d7  (cost=0.00..4.19 rows=5 width=0) (never executed)
                                         Index Cond: (playlist_id = u1.id)
                     SubPlan 7
                       ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on videos_tag u0_3  (cost=0.00..93.23 rows=6 width=16) (actual time=15.863..15.916 rows=18 loops=1)
                             Recheck Cond: (name &@~ 'word'::character varying)
                             Heap Blocks: exact=12
                             ->  Bitmap Index Scan on pgroonga_tag_index  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=55 width=0) (actual time=0.514..0.514 rows=18 loops=1)
                                   Index Cond: (name &@~ 'word'::character varying)
 Planning Time: 2.311 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 78
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 11.664 ms, Inlining 14.842 ms, Optimization 298.550 ms, Emission 183.883 ms, Total 508.939 ms
 Execution Time: 5330.376 ms
(48 rows)

Time: 5333.552 ms (00:05.334)
```

Comment: ->  Seq Scan on videos_video_tags, check for the missing indexes

Comment: There is an index in videos_video_tags, but for some reason it is not being used.

Comment: create index for is_public, published_at, title

Comment: I've added a list of related indexes to the question: why are the indexes title, is_public, published_at, and name not being used?

Comment: try creating a multi column index, in the same order used in the query, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/indexes-multicolumn.html

Comment: I tried creating it, but it didn't improve the situation. is there a problem with the combined index of title, is_public, and published_at?

Answer (score 0):

You may have complex sub-queries but that is **not** first attack you need for better execution. Here is the culprit: `Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 12232kB`. You are doing a DISK sort rather than in memory. You need to increase work_mem.

> work_mem (integer)
>
> Sets the base maximum amount of memory to be used by a query operation >(such as a sort or hash table) before writing to temporary disk files.

Comment: I was able to increase the work_mem and change the DISK sort to Memory sort, but the speed was not nearly as good.